# How can I display if an airline departs from all the airport in my DB in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE airlines (
    airline_name VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE airport (
    code VARCHAR UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    category VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE volo (
    code VARCHAR UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    departure_time TIME(0) NOT NULL,
    departure_airport VARCHAR NOT NULL REFERENCES aeroporto(codice),
    arrival_time TIME(0) NOT NULL,
    arrival_airport VARCHAR NOT NULL REFERENCES aeroporto(codice),
    airline VARCHAR NOT NULL REFERENCES airlines(airline_name)
);
```

I need to display which airline departs from all the airport in my DB. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and count the `departure_airport`:

```
select v.airline
from volo v
group by v.airline
having count(distinct departure_airport) = (select count(*) from airport);
```

Comment: Thanks that was perfect!