# How to set a trigger in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, plpgsql

I have the tables show here -> [How can I display if an airline departs from all the airport in my DB in Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941977/how-can-i-display-if-an-airline-departs-from-all-the-airport-in-my-db-in-postgre)

I've update the airlines table like below

```
ALTER TABLE airlines
ADD COLUMN count_flight INTEGER;
```

Now I need to update the column count_flight with the number of flight for each airline that are already stored in volo table.

How can I set a trigger that do what I need + update the value of count_flight every time I insert a new row in volo table?

EDIT

I've set a trigger like below and it works

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_flight() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $updateN_voli$
DECLARE
    airline_name varchar;
    
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        airline_name = NEW.airline;
        UPDATE airlines
        SET count_flight = count_flight + 1
        WHERE airline_name = airlines.airline_name;
END IF;
RETURN NULL;    
END;
$updateN_voli$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

/* Creo il trigger */
CREATE TRIGGER update_flight
AFTER INSERT ON volo
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_flight();

Now I can't figure out how can I update the value with the existing flight. As I said in the comment below I have found a possible solution but is a bit complex if I have a big amount of row in table volo.
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: One rule of database design is to not store information that can be derived from existing data. Rather than updating a column through a trigger, a view that calculates that value would be more appropriate

Comment: There are two things - initial update (where you will fill `count_flight` for already existing rows) and trigger which will allow to do it during inserts (here you have how it looks like https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/plpgsql-trigger.html). But both of these point would need to slightly more logic as it's about a counting items from `volo` grouping by `airlines`. Please provide some minimal working example with inserts into rows (https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and that will allow us to help you to create it.

Comment: For update count_flight I tried this:
`UPDATE compagnie SET num_voli = (SELECT COUNT (compagnia) FROM volo WHERE compagnia = 'x')
WHERE compagnia = 'x';`
It works but in this way I need to write the UPDATE for every single airline in the table. Maybe exist some sort of a loop function that can help me to execute it for every single row in the table?
For the trigger I don't know how to set the function properly. I only know how to create a trigger itself:
`CREATE TRIGGER count
AFTER INSERT ON volo
EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_name();`

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer:

This is for update the column with existing data in volo table:

```
DO 
$$
DECLARE
    a varchar;

BEGIN
    FOR a IN select airline from airlines LOOP
        UPDATE airlines
        SET count_flight = (SELECT COUNT (airline) FROM volo WHERE airline = a)
        WHERE airline = a;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

This is for update te airlines table every time a new flight is add to volo table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_newVoli() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $updateN_voli$
DECLARE
    name_airline varchar;
    
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        name_airline = NEW.airline;
        UPDATE compagnie
        SET count_flight = count_flight + 1
        WHERE name_airline = airlines.airline;
END IF;
RETURN NULL;    
END;
$updateN_voli$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_newVoli
AFTER INSERT ON volo
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_newVoli();
```